# Generate script for creating XmlSerializers.dll in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio, sqlclr

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 and I wrote some CLR SQL assembly and deployed it on several SQL Servers. I added stored procedure that calls web service to this assembly, and when i tried to re-deploy my assembly, it failed on one of the servers.
I've got an error:
Cannot load dynamically generated serialization assembly. In some hosting environments assembly load functionality is restricted, consider using pre-generated serializer.
I'm creating assembly and stored procedures using script generated by VS (MySolution.MyProject_Create.sql). This script creates assembly:

```
    CREATE ASSEMBLY [AssemblyName]
    AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
    FROM 0xx4D5A9(....)
    WITH PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS;
```

But there is no command for creating XmlSerializers.dll file, so I have to copy this file to remote server, and run command:

```
    CREATE ASSEMBLY [AssemblyName.XmlSerializers] FROM
    'C:\path\AssemblyName.XmlSerializers.dll'
    WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
```

And then script XmlSerializers.dll manually to avoid copying this file to other servers.

Is this possible to change some settings so Visual Studio will generate create script for XMLSerializers.dll, too?

Answer (score 1):

Go to project properties, build tab, and set "Generate serialization asssembly" to On.

Comment: It's set to "ON", and serialization assembly is being generated, but it's just not included in SQL script file.

Comment: Are you looking for a command to generate this file? There is a tool called sgen.exe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bk3w6240.aspx

Comment: No, as I said, i successfully generated this file, I just wanted to know if it's possible to include CREATE ASSEMBLY for this XmlSerializers dll file in MySolution.MyProject_Create.sql Script generated by Visual Studio (and if it is possible, how to do so)